# rhino mocks usage of AssertWasNotCalled

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I made following stub

```
    _Service.Stub(s => s.Login(Arg<string>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Is.Anything, Arg<int>.Is.Anything, out ggg)).OutRef(55);
```

the last parameter is a `out` parameter of type `int`.

I want to make following Assert

```
    _Service.AssertWasNotCalled(s => s.Login(Arg<string>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Is.Anything,Arg<int>.Is.Anything , ??????? ));
```

But how I note `out` parameter here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Simply" use:

```
_Service.AssertWasNotCalled(s => s.Login(
    Arg<string>.Is.Anything,
    Arg<string>.Is.Anything,
    Arg<int>.Is.Anything ,
    out Arg<int>.Out(10).Dummy
));
```

The value passed to `Out` method is irrelevant (.`Dummy` call is the important one).

Answer (score 3):

Mock assertion usually applied to mocks not stubs. So you could rewrite code to have following setup

```
_Service.Expect(s => s.Login(Arg<string>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Is.Anything, Arg<int>.Is.Anything, out ggg)).OutRef(55).Repeat.Never();
```

And mke verification at *Assert* part of test

```
_Service.VerifyAllExpectations();
```